# Is there an STL algo that takes predicate for summing up the elements of a vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector, stl, c++17, c++20

I've been working on an assignment to understand all STL algorithms given in C++ library and we're supposed to avoid using for_each and for loop for solving the questions. For the most part I was able to find applicable STL algorithms but I couldn't remember any which summed up a collection or a range while using a predicate and I couldn't find a solution on the forum as well. I'm using C++ 20.

The only objective is to sum the even numbers in a vector to a variable, using STL algorithms.

Comment: [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)

Comment: I tried accumulate but it doesn't take a predicate. Hence, it can't distinguish between odd or even and sums them all up.

Comment: `[](auto x, auto y) { return y%2==0 ? x+y : x; }`?

Comment: Yeah, I would try that lambda, but the accumulate doesn't have an overload that accepts a lambda. Otherwise I would have to use for_each with a predicate or a for loop inside a lambda. Which I have been asked to avoid.

Comment: Accumulate has an overload that accepts a _binary_ function, whose first argument is the total and second argument is the summand. You can of course make the behavior of this function conditioned on the parity of the second argument.

Comment: I believe the overload you're talking about is the binary _operator_, which let's one perform other binary operations than sum, if I'm not wrong. I'm sorry, I couldn't find any predicated overloads, are you sure?

Comment: @RaviSharma The _BinaryOperation_ takes two operands. You may do what you like with those. You return the new total from the function, like I showed in my answer.

Comment: @RaviSharma Correct, it doesn't take a predicate. But it doesn't need to. Ted's answer demonstrates how you can write an operator which only performs the addition if the right-hand side is even.

Comment: I'm sorry, and thank you so much, it worked, But I'm still trying to understand what exactly happened and how it's working. I realized that it's like passing two "arguments" to an operator, and works similarly with the lambda that we're passing, right? and x and y are the current sum and current element, right?

Comment: The operator takes two arguments, the current total and the new term. The return value is assigned to be the new current total. It then repeatedly applies this operator to your initial value for each element in the iterator range. Essentially instead of repeatedly calling `total = total + newTerm`, you're repeatedly calling `total = binaryOperation(total, newTerm)`.

Comment: @NathanPierson thanks, totally understand it now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate).

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

int main() {   
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,5};
    auto result = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0,
        [](auto x, auto y) {
            return y%2==0 ? x+y : x; 
        });
    std::cout << result << '\n';  // prints 6
}
```